# SharePoint Ecma Get List Properties

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, ecmascript-5, ecma

I am trying to read a List Properties using SharePoint ECMA but could not success.

Anyone can help - here is the code - tried with method get_fieldValues and get_item and both have returned "undefined".

```
var key = "vti_level";
function getListProperty() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var listGuid = GetUrlKeyValue('List', window.location.href);
    this.props = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById(listGuid).get_rootFolder();
    clientContext.load(this.props);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, getListPropertySuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, getListPropertyFailed));
}

function getListPropertySuccess() {
    var propKey1 = this.props.get_properties().get_fieldValues()[key];
    var propKey2 = this.props.get_properties().get_item(key);
}

function getListPropertyFailed() {
    alert('Request failed on getListProperty.');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    var key = "vti_level";

        function getListProperty() {
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
            var listGuid = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId;
            this.props = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById(listGuid).get_rootFolder().get_properties();
            clientContext.load(this.props);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, getListPropertySuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, getListPropertyFailed));
    }
    function getListPropertySuccess() {
        var propKey1 = this.props.get_fieldValues()[key];
        var propKey2 = this.props.get_item(key);
    }
    function getListPropertyFailed() {
        alert('Request failed on getListProperty.');
    }
```